# Does getenv() change its behaviour when using dup()?

Tags: c, linux

I'm implementing my own *shell* in C, having built-ins commands like `cd` between many.

My cd works like that:

`cd PATH` where `PATH` can be null, which means I simply have to `chdir` to the variable `getenv("HOME")`

This part works completely fine, except for one point:
One of the requirements is that my shell has to have the ability to redirect its `stdout` or `stdin` even for the builtins because my `cd` has to print the `cwd`.

```
cd /home/user/ > file1
```

should create `file1` with the `cwd` as output: `/home/user/`

When I run gdb with my program, I actually can see the value of `newDir` being `/home/user/` but then the `chdir` executes and fails, telling there is no such file. I observed this only happen when I redirect the stdin and stdout (I do it correctly in the program that actually calls `cd` method).

Here is the important part of `cd`:

```
if(argc==1){
    newDir = getenv("HOME");

}else{
    if(strstr(argvv[1],"home") || strstr(argvv[1],"~")){
        newDir=argvv[1];
    }else{
    char * oldDir = getcwd(buf,sizeof(buf));
    newDir = strcat(oldDir, "/");
    newDir = strcat(newDir, argvv[1]);
    }
}


if(chdir(newDir)<0){
    //Error handler
}else
    printf("%s\n",getcwd(buf,sizeof(buf)));

return;
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] that we can run ourselves. Include the code that performs redirections and the output from your program when it fails.

Comment: I meant to do a question more tan to ask about my own code, just put it there to let you know how I reached to that question. So my question is more about: ¿Does duping Will afect to the getenv? Like, does duping a file descriptor actually modifies in some way the environment?

Comment: Where do you call dup? Anyway, no. Duping a file descriptor does not change the environment, nor does it do anything else other dup the fd. Your problem is that your code makes no attempt to handle the case where the argument is an absolute file path. It just assumes the argument will be relative, and appends it to $CWD. That's obviously not going to work with `/home/user`

Comment: Are you sure there's no trailing characters such as a line feed?

Comment: @rici maybe that's the problem, how do I implement to check the diference between relative and absolut? I tried using ````strstr```` as you see to check if he used ````home```` or ````~````. Anyways I'm getting a problem when I change the stds just before entering cd command, because my chdir says "no such file" when looking for ````/home/user````. I don't see anything related to difference between relative and absolut neither on the ````chdir```` manual.
@ikegami getenv says nothing about trailing characters so I suppose it returns a normal string terminates by the ````NULL```` character.

Answer (score 2):

No, duping a file descriptor does not change the environment. There's no connection between the two.